# Force encoding when writing txt file with ofstream

Tags: c++, windows, encoding, character-encoding

I writing a txt file using ofstream, from various reasons the file should have local encoding and not UTF8.
The machine which process the file has different localizations then the target local.

is there a way to force the encoding when writing a file?

regards,

Ilan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `std::ios::imbue` on your `ofstream` object to modify the locale. This won't affect the global locale.

```
std::ofstream os("output.txt");
std::locale mylocale(""); 
os.imbue(mylocale);
os << 1.5f << std::endl;
os.close();
```

Pay attention to the argument of `std::locale` constructor, it is implementation dependant. For example, the German locale could be :

```
std::locale mylocale("de_DE");
```

or

```
std::locale mylocale("German");
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, given that it's Windows, you'd not have UTF8 anyway. But exactly what are you writing? Usually, you have a `std::string` in memory and write that to disk. The only difference is that `\n` in memory is translated to CR/LF (`\r\n`) on disk. That's the same translation everywhere.

You might encounter a situation where you're writing a `std::wstring`. In that case, it's determined by the locale. The default locale is the C locale, aka `std::locale("C") or`std::locale::classic()`. The local encoding (which you seem to want) is`std::locale("")`.

Other locales exist; see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4406895/what-stdlocale-names-are-available-on-common-windows-compilers)

Comment: Windows uses UTF16 since 2000 but has no trouble using UTF8.