# std::get_time and other locale functionality not working correctly on Windows

Tags: c++, visual-c++, locale, c++11, iomanip

In my attempts to make libc++ and its tests work on Windows, I have come to a problem I can't seem to wrap my head around. The following code is taken from libc++ test code, and passes on Mac (aand probably FreeBSD as well), but not with MinGW-w64 nor MSVC 2010 SP1.

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

template <class CharT>
struct testbuf
    : public std::basic_streambuf<CharT>
{
    typedef std::basic_string<CharT> string_type;
    typedef std::basic_streambuf<CharT> base;
private:
    string_type str_;
public:

    testbuf() {}
    testbuf(const string_type& str)
        : str_(str)
    {
        base::setg(const_cast<CharT*>(str_.data()),
                   const_cast<CharT*>(str_.data()),
                   const_cast<CharT*>(str_.data()) + str_.size());
    }
};
#if _WIN32
#define LOCALE_en_US_UTF_8 "English_USA.1252"
#else
#define LOCALE_en_US_UTF_8 "en_US.UTF-8"
#endif
int main()
{
    testbuf<char> sb("  Sat Dec 31 23:55:59 2061");
    std::istream is(&sb);
    is.imbue(std::locale(LOCALE_en_US_UTF_8));
    std::tm t = {0};
    is >> std::get_time(&t, "%c");
    std::cout << t.tm_sec << "\n";
    std::cout << t.tm_min << "\n";
    std::cout << t.tm_hour << "\n";
    std::cout << t.tm_mday << "\n";
    std::cout << t.tm_mon << "\n";
    std::cout << t.tm_year << "\n";
    std::cout << t.tm_wday << "\n";
    assert(t.tm_sec == 59);
    assert(t.tm_min == 55);
    assert(t.tm_hour == 23);
    assert(t.tm_mday == 31);
    assert(t.tm_mon == 11);
    assert(t.tm_year == 161);
    assert(t.tm_wday == 6);
}
```

The test passes for Mac/FreeBSD, but the different element are all 0 for Windows. This is true for MinGW-w64+libc++ and MSVC10+Microsoft's STL.

Is this just crappy locale support in Windows or is there a wrong implementation-dependent assumption (input format) at play here I can fix or work around?

Comment: Clare: every single one: all the elements are just 0 instead of the values expected in the asserts.

Comment: Hmm, yes, I see what you mean. In Visual C++ 2010 Express, I get all zeroes too - with a default-created C++ console application.

Comment: Are those even the kind and format of locales that Windows accepts? Windows lives in UTF-16 world, so I doubt they support a lot of UTF-8 locales.

Comment: Nicol Bolas: Note that I cheated and used the Windows codepage in the `UTF_8` define. Especially for plain English (en_US), this simple example should work. `istream::imbue` is not failing. I verified that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem exposed here is not
 - Wrong locale names
 - Wrong `std::tm` values

But lies exactly in the fact that the `%c` format specifier does not do what's expected here on Windows. This is easy to fix, by specifying the format in full. In this case, what I used was:

```
"%a %b %d %H" ":" "%M" ":" "%S %Y"
```

It still has problems with the `%Y` part (`tm_year` is still zero)...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not convinced you have the right locale string. They seem to be really badly documented, although there's what looks like a good list [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hzz3tw78.aspx).

Perhaps "american_us.1252"? (These strings are all implementation-defined, of course.)

Comment: See [here](http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Table_of_locales) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4406895/what-stdlocale-names-are-available-on-common-windows-compilers/4497266#4497266) but [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb895996.aspx) seems to suggest different naming... I'm confused :(