# What information is used when parsing a (float) number?

Tags: c++, c, locale, iostream, scanf

### What information does the Standard library of C++ use when parsing a (float) number?

Here's the possibilities I know to parse a (single) float number with std c++:

- [`double atof( const char *str )`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atof)
- [`sscanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf)
- [`double strtod( const char* str, char** str_end );`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtof)
- [`istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream), via `operator>>` or
- via [`num_get`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/num_get) directly

It seems obvious, that *at the very least*, we have to know what character is used as decimal separator.

iostreams, in particular [`num_get::get`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/num_get/get), *in addition* also talk about:

- `ios_base` I/O format flags - **Is there *any* information here that is used when parsing *floating point*?**
- the `thousands_sep`arator (* **see below**)

On the other hand, in `std::strtod`, which seems to be what `sscanf` is defined in terms of (which in turn is referenced by `num_get`), there the only variable information seems to be what is [considered a space](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isspace) and the decimal character, although it doesn't seem to be specified where *that* is defined. (At least neither on cppref nor on MSDN.)

So, what information is actually used, and what comprises a valid parseable float representation for the C++ Standard lib?

From what I see, only the decimal separator from the global (`C`or `C++` ???) is needed and, in addition, if the number contains a thousands separator, I would expect it to only be parsed correctly by `num_get` since `strod`/`sscanf` do not support the thousands separator.

---

(*) The group (thousands) separator is an interesting case to me. As far as I can tell the "`C`" functions do not make *any* reference to it and last time I checked `C` and `C++` standard `printf` function will never write it. So is it really processed by the `strtod`/`scanf` functions? (I know that there is a POSIX *printf* extension for the group separator, but that's not really standard, and notably missing from Microsoft's implementation.)

Comment: All of them should be using the current locale to determine thousands-separator and decimal-point characters.

Comment: `sscanf(3)` (and `scanf(3)`, and `fscanf(3)`, and also `strtod(3)`) are C functions, provided for backwards compatibility. They (as their C++ counterparts) should respect the locale settings.

Comment: @vonbrand - The definition of `num_get::get` even references `sscanf`. For me, they are fully valid standard C++ functions.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg - see my edit wrt. thousands-separator

Comment: @MartinBa, they are fully valid, but C legacy/compatibility. I.e, better don't use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C11 spec for `strtod()` seems to have a opening big enough for any size truck to drive through.  It appears so open ended, I see no limitation.

> §7.22.1.3 6 In other than the "C" locale, additional locale-specific subject sequence forms may be accepted.

---

For non- "standard C" locales, the `isspace()`, decimal (radix) point, group separator, digits per group and sign seem to constitute the typical variants.  But apparently there is no limit.

---

For fun *experimented* with 500+ locales using `printf()`, `sscanf()`, `strftime()` and `isspace()`.

All tested locales had a radix (decimal) point of `'.'` or `','`, the same +/- sign, no digit grouping, and the expected 0-9.

`strftime(... "%Y" ...)`  did not use a digit separator over years 1000-99999.

`sscanf("1,234.5", "%lf", ..` and `sscanf("1.234,5", "%lf", ..` did not produce 1234.5 in any locale.

All `int` values in the range 0 to 255 produced the same `isspace()` results with the sometimes exception of 154 and 160.

Of course these test do not *prove* a limit to what may occur, but do represent a sample of possibilities.

Comment: Also see (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4406895/what-stdlocale-names-are-available-on-common-windows-compilers)