# What is the locale name for Korean?

Tags: c++, locale

More specificly, in C++:

```
#include <locale>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main() {
    std::wstring v[3] = {L"홍진호", L"이상민", L"장동민"};
    std::locale loc("Korean.949");
    std::sort(v, v + 3, loc);
    std::wcout.imbue(loc);
    std::wcout << v[0] << ' ' << v[1] << ' ' << v[2] << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This doesn't work. I'm using Windows 10 64bit, MinGW, and GNU GCC 4.9.2.

What is the locale name for Korean, for loc?

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4497266/1670021

Looks like on Windows with gcc, this may not work well.  You might be able to use the C `setlocale`, but that's not a great option.  Maybe using a blank string would work for your use case?

Comment: That might be a problem, but that is not the point here. "Korean.949" is not valid name, so I am asking what the correct is.

Comment: Well, you can try ".949" or "ko_KR".  See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4406895/what-stdlocale-names-are-available-on-common-windows-compilers - locale names are implementation defined.

Comment: That name is valid, but unfornunately, MinGW doesn't support wide characters... I used narrow characters instead, but I get this weird output: ?띿쭊???댁긽誘??λ룞誘
?댁긽誘??λ룞誘??띿쭊?